# merging many jsonb objects using aggregate functions in PostgreSQL?

Tags: aggregate, json, postgresql-12

Is there a standard function in PostgreSQL (as of 12.x) to concatenate or merge many jsonb objects in a database column into a single jsonb object?

I know there is a the [||](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html) operator since PostgreSQL 9.5 to merge **two** jsonb objects. But I need to merge many jsonb objects from a column. The linked documentation does not seem to have one unless I am missing something.

Comment: Something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42944888

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and this post solved it:

https://blog.faraday.io/how-to-aggregate-jsonb-in-postgres/

The idea is to create an aggregate:

> ```
> CREATE AGGREGATE jsonb_object_agg(jsonb) (
>   SFUNC = 'jsonb_concat',
>   STYPE = jsonb,
>   INITCOND = '{}'
> );
> ```

See the linked article for more details.

Comment: Using the name `jsonb_object_agg` is dangerous, because that's also the name of a built-in aggregate function

Comment: Your link is dead, can you update it or link to it via internet archive?